# SSIS - Cannot connect to SP List with OData Source

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have a SSIS Package with an OData Source Connection to a SharePoint List. To connect to the list, I have a Service Account, which I add as Basic Authentification in the OData Source Task. With this Credentials I can connect to SP and can choose the collection (also preview of the list).

When I now execute the Package (in VS or from Management Studio) the package always fails with the error Message "Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager".

In Management Studio I run the Package with the Service Account User.

Does everybody know whats my problem here ?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Might be a 32/64 bit problem... see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdm/2011/05/11/why-cant-my-package-acquire-a-connection-from-its-connection-manager/) for more info.